# Stemming process not working in Python

Tags: python, stemming

I have a text file that I am trying to `stem` after having removed `stopwords` but it seems that nothing changes when I run it. My file is called `data0`.

Here are my codes:

```
## Removing stopwords and tokenizing by words (split each word)
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

data0 = word_tokenize(data0)
data0 = ' '.join([word for word in data0 if word not in (stopwords.words('english'))])
print(data0)

## Stemming the data
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer

ps = PorterStemmer()
data0 = ps.stem(data0)
print(data0)
```

And I get the following (wrapped for legibility):

> For us around Aberdeen , question `` What oil industry ? ( Evening Express , October 26 ) touch deja vu . That question asked almost since day first drop oil pumped North Sea . In past 30 years seen constant cycle ups downs , booms busts industry . I predict happen next . There period worry uncertainty scrabble find something keep local economy buoyant oil gone . Then upturn see jobs investment oil , everyone breathe sigh relief quest diversify go back burner . That downfall . Major industries prone collapse . Look nation 's defunct shipyards extinct coal steel industries . That 's vital n't panic downturns , start planning sensibly future . Our civic business leaders need constantly looking something secure prosperity - tourism , technology , bio-science emerging industries . We need economically strong rather waiting see happens oil roller coaster hits buffers . N JonesEllon

The first part of the code works fine (Removing stopwords and tokenizing), but us the second part (Stem) which does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: Could you update your question with the output you get. What 'does not work' about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Stemmer docs http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html, it looks like the Stemmer is designed to be called on a single word at a time.

Try running it on each word in

```
[word for word in data0 if word not in (stopwords.words('english'))]
```

I.e. before calling join

E.g.

```
stemmed_list = []
for str in [word for word in data0 if word not in (stopwords.words('english'))]:
    stemmed_list.append(ps.stem(str))
```

Edit: Comment Response.
I ran the following - and it seemed to stem correctly:

```
>>> from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
>>> ps = PorterStemmer()
>>> data0 = '''<Your Data0 string>'''
>>> words = data0.split(" ")
>>> stemmed_words = map(ps.stem, words)
>>> print(list(stemmed_words))  # list cast needed because of 'map'
[..., 'industri', ..., 'diversifi']
```

I don't think there is a stemmer that can be applied straight to text, but you can wrap it in your own function that takes 'ps' and the text:

```
def my_stem(text, stemmer):
    words = text.split(" ")
    stemmed_words = map(stemmer, words)
    result = " ".join(list(stemmed_words))
    return result
```

Comment: Or just `[ps.stem(word) for word in data0` etc etc

Comment: @Tom Rees, the good looks great but it seems that still gives me the same outcome. Since the PorterStemmer is designed to  be called on a single word at a time, is there other stemmer functions that can be applied to whole texts? Thanks

Comment: @AndresAzqueta, I've edited the answer in response to your comment. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I've done in the past w/NLTK:

```
st = PorterStemmer()

def stem_tokens(tokens):
    for item in tokens:
        yield st.stem(item)

def go(text):
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)

    return ' '.join(stem_tokens(tokens))
```